# Automatically setting properties in SQLAlchemy declarative models

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is a contrived example of what I'm trying to do. I have child objects that could by one of two categories of related object (here 'home and 'work').

I was wondering if there's a sensible way of having the column that determines which category they are in (`Address.type`) automatically set when they are bound using their respective relationships.

Maybe there's a better way of handling this situation generally?

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    home_addresses = relationship('Address', primaryjoin="and_(Person.id==Address.person_id, Address.type == 'home')")
    work_addresses = relationship('Address', primaryjoin="and_(Person.id==Address.person_id, Address.type == 'work')")


class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    person_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('person.id'))
    type = Column(String)


p = Person()
p.home_addresses.append(Address())  # automatically set type to 'home'
p.work_addresses.append(Address())  # automatically set type to 'work'
```

Comment: It may be possible but explicit is better than implicit I think.

Comment: I think you're probably right, Simon. I'm just going to do it explicitly for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [orm events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents.append)

```
from sqlalchemy import event
@event.listens_for(Person.home_addresses, 'append')
def receive_append(target, value, initiator):
    # set the address type to home
    value.type = 'home'
    return value
```